# modify pixels of an CGImageRef

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgimage

I am using the following code to modify pixels of an image.
The issue I have is the color of the images are icorrect.
Do you have any idea of the issue?

`CGImageRef inImage = img.CGImage;

    CGContextRef ctx;`

```
    CFDataRef m_DataRef; 
    m_DataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage)); 
    UInt8 * m_PixelBuf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(m_DataRef); 
//    Byte tmpByte; 
    int length = CFDataGetLength(m_DataRef); 

    for (int index = 0; index < length; index += 4) 
    { 
    //    DO Stuff 

    } 

    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(m_PixelBuf, 
                                CGImageGetWidth( inImage ), 
                                CGImageGetHeight( inImage ), 
                                8, 
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow( inImage ), 
                                CGImageGetColorSpace( inImage ), 
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst ); 


    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx); 
    UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 

    CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

Comment: Maybe you should show what you do with 'DO Stuff' .. Alao, why not do a mini experiment and set all pixels to red. Then you will probably find out if you are addressing them wrong or not.

Comment: Even if I do nothing, the image is modified. The issue is not with the processing code.

Comment: How is it modified? Do color channels get swapped or does the image get distorted? Did you try changing kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst  to a result of CGImageGetAlphaInfo()?

Comment: Image is not distorted. It seems that color channels are swapped. The tricky thing is that it works in teh simulator and not on the device. I am going to try  CGImageGetAlphaInfo()

Comment: I tried CGImageGetAlphaInfo() but the image is still blue.

Comment: Perhaps your alpha value comes last? In which case try using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` instead of `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst`.